# How do I create a Google+ circle for a user?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, sdk, google-plus

I've added the Google+ SDK for iOS into my project.

I want to create a circle on behalf of the user, but I'm not sure if there's a way to do that.

The Google+ domains API allows that. The name suggests it to be a sub-category of the Google+ API, which had me confused for a while, but it actually appears to be a separate thing, designed for companies to host a company-wide social network using Google+. It also doesn't accept a Google+ access token, and only allows you to work with users on a specific Google Apps domain.

So that's out of the question, and I'm back to where I began.

Is there a way for me to create a Google+ circle and add people to it on behalf of a user?

Answer (score 0):

The standard Google+ API does not provide access to creating or managing circles. There is a [feature request you can star](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=52) if this is something you are interested in.